# Simple but nested SELECT query

Tags: sql, select, join, union

I have four tables `a,b,c,d`. In table `a` I have pair of `id, name`. In table `b` I have pair of `idx, idy`. The `b.idy` comes from table `a.id`. In tables `c, d` I have pair of `id, value` which are related to table `b.idx`.

I have to perform a query like this:

```
SELECT c.value, d.value 
FROM a,b,c,d
WHERE a.name = "test" AND b.idy = a.id AND (c.id = b.idx AND d.id = b.idx)
```

The problem is sometimes there are missing records in tables `c, d` so `AND` will return zero records, but I need to have results if there are available either in `c` or `d`. Also I can't use `OR` because it returns other rows also for both tables.

I guess there would be a solution using `UNION` or even just nested `SELECT`s. I prefer to do not use `JOIN` or using separated quires.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

The reason for avoiding using `JOIN` is performance. The structure that I'm working on now is much more complex rather than this one, so I'm sure with `JOIN` I would have serious performance issues in the upcoming future.

Comment: Why do you not prefer JOINs? This appears to be a classical `LEFT JOIN` use case.

Comment: I explained the reason on the original post

Comment: And actually you're already using a JOIN. What did you think `FROM a,b,c,d` meant? As for performance, "not getting the correct results" looks like a serious performance issue to me...

Comment: @lserni I'm not sure if "FROM a,b,c,d" is equal to "JOIN" ...

Comment: a,b,c,d would be an INNER JOIN in the best case and a CARTESIAN PRODUCT in the worst case. So, it's no better than an explicit JOIN statement if you already know the relationship among them and the columns involved in those relationships.

Comment: @Mahdi the comma syntax is a `JOIN` since you are then specifying the fields to join on in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: It is. It is a `CROSS JOIN`, which can actually be *far more expensive* than a `LEFT JOIN`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join

Comment: thank you all, but what is the difference between 'RedFilter' and 'bluefeet' answers? which one is more efficient in this case? are they same?

Comment: @lserni I am not sure what *It is.* refers to in your comment, but if you mean the query in the question, you are incorrect. The `WHERE` clause in this query prevents it from being a `CROSS JOIN` in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.value, d.value 
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.idy
LEFT JOIN c
    ON b.idx = c.id
LEFT JOIN d
    ON b.idx = d.id
WHERE a.name = "test"
```

Using the comma join syntax is an `INNER JOIN` which requires that the records be available in all tables.

If you need help in reviewing `JOIN` syntax there is a helpful guide:

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks bluefeet! it's working and it's slightly faster than 'RedFilter' solution. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.value, d.value
from a
inner join b on b.idy = a.id
left outer join c on c.id = b.idx
left outer join d on d.id = b.idx
where a.name = "test" 
    and coalesce(c.id, d.id) is not null
```

Comment: Thanks RedFilter, I test your query, it's working! :) ... gonna test other answers ...

Comment: @Mahdi To clarify the functionality of my query, it only returns records where there is a match in tables `a` *and* `b`, as well as a match in either `c` *or* `d`.

Comment: yes, but it's slightly slower than 'bluefeet' query. Do you know why? is there any advantages on using your query? thanks again!

Comment: @Mahdi they are functionally quite different. E.g., you said *I need to have results if there are available either in c or d*. My query has this functionality, bluefeet's does not.

Comment: no, I test that, all of three quires here bring the same results, just different in performance. I'm sure, I test that on my real tables ... I'll go check it out again ...

Comment: @Mahdi You are incorrect. You must not have sufficient data to test properly. In fact, all 3 answers are quite different.

Comment: oh, it's getting a little bit complicated I guess ... thank you for your guide, I guess I should start reading more about it ... I really have no idea what is the differences that you're talking about ... if you have time, could you please update your answer and briefly compare all three quires. I'm sure that I can't do that, thanks ...

Comment: @Mahdi I am confused by your eagerness to implement queries that you do not understand. Your question is not complicated, and the differences between the answers are not that subtle. You just need to do some learning about SQL in general, which I urge you to do before implementing anything further. If you have a specific question about something you don't understand, I am happy to answer, but I am not going to lay everything out for you, that's just too big of an ask.

Comment: thanks! :D ... I know that, you're right! I'll put 'SQL' on my schedule! Thank you anyways, I learned many things here with you guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.value, d.value 
FROM a,b,c,d
WHERE a.name = "test" AND b.idy = a.id AND (c.id = b.idx AND d.id = b.idx)
UNION
SELECT c.value, NULL
FROM a,b,c
WHERE a.name = "test" AND b.idy = a.id AND c.id = b.idx AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL FROM d where d.id = b.idx )
UNION
SELECT NULL, d.value
FROM a,b,d
WHERE a.name = "test" AND b.idy = a.id AND d.id = b.idx AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL FROM c where c.id = b.idx )
```

Comment: Thank you JosephH! your query works but it's several times slower than the others. However I know that I asked to do it via 'UNION' or nested 'SELECT's. Thank you anyways! :)

Comment: @Mahdi I think the primary benefit of using this is that you can set the value of the `(NULL)` when the row doesn't exist in either c or d. As far as I know, I don't think it's possible if you are using `JOIN`

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what it exactly means. could you please explain a little bit more, thanks ...

Comment: @Mahdi so if a row doesn't exist in the table c (or d), the query will simply return NULL for column where the value doesn't exist. If you use `UNION` like this, you can choose what kind of value you want to return explicitly in the result. e.g. `SELECT "The value doesn't exist on the table c", d.value FROM a,b,d,...`

Comment: Thanks, got it better! However, the execution time is so slow for me, and I guess I would go finally for 'JOIN' as it's more efficient in my case! Thank you again for the answer and all the descriptions, I learned very good points here in these answers ... :)