# Simple SQL JOIN Query

Tags: sql, join

I'm still struggling difficulties with even simple `JOIN` queries. From my last question, [Simple but nested SELECT query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517961/simple-but-nested-select-query), I learned many things, but still couldn't accomplish my `JOIN` queries. :(

I have this query from the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517961/simple-but-nested-select-query), and it's working:

```
SELECT c.value, d.value 
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.idy
LEFT JOIN c
    ON b.idx = c.id
LEFT JOIN d
    ON b.idx = d.id
WHERE a.name = "test"
```

Now, I want to add another conditions to the query to look on tables `e,f,g` and if any of `a.id, b.idx, c.id, d.id` **DOESN'T** exists on the tables `e,f,g`, then return the results. For example if `c.id` exists on `e.id` then it should eliminates the row from table `c`. If `a.id` exists on `g.id`, it should not continue because if you took off the `a.id` from the query, the other parts should not return anything.

I've made a sample database structure which you can see the sql code here: [Sample.sql](http://freetexthost.com/m2wc4okaq1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
SELECT c.value, d.value 
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.idy
    AND b.id NOT IN (SELECT e.id FROM e UNION ALL SELECT f.id FROM f UNION ALL SELECT g.id FROM g)
LEFT JOIN c
    ON b.idx = c.id
    AND c.id NOT IN (SELECT e.id FROM e UNION ALL SELECT f.id FROM f UNION ALL SELECT g.id FROM g)
LEFT JOIN d
    ON b.idx = d.id
    AND d.id NOT IN (SELECT e.id FROM e UNION ALL SELECT f.id FROM f UNION ALL SELECT g.id FROM g)
WHERE a.name = "test" 
AND a.id NOT IN (SELECT e.id FROM e UNION ALL SELECT f.id FROM f UNION ALL SELECT g.id FROM g)
```

Comment: Hey, it works, but when I have for example 'c.id' in 'f', then it returns both 'NULL' values for 'c.value, d.value'. By the way I want it returns only 'NULL' for 'c.value' or at least '0' rows not a pair of 'NULL' values. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your SQL dialect, but with MySQL you could use:

```
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM e WHERE e.idx = b.idx)
```

Comment: thanks! why select 1? i can use 'select null'? it's the same?

Comment: _exists_ checks for the presence of at least one row, so you can select anything, null included

Comment: also, please use @lc 's answer which is actually more accurate than mine ^^;